# AlertCondition triggering early

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have converted a strategy to an indicator, basically share the same code, only the header and footer code is different.

The strategy works as I expect.

Say for example running on a 5min chart on the 10:30 bar the triggering conditions may occur several times but I am only concerned with the close of the bar and then trigger a strategy entry only if the conditions exist at the close of the bar.

TV shows in its trade list that the trade was executed correctly at exactly 10:35

With the indicator, I am using AlertCondition to trigger an alert that will eventually trigger a trade elsewhere.

In the same conditions as above the alert is triggering at the start of the 10:30 bar not
10:35.

```
alertcondition(buySignal and barstate.isconfirmed, title="Alert Buy", message="Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal and barstate.isconfirmed, title="Alert: Sell", message="Sell!")
```

So I am using barstate.isconfirmed to ensure the alert only triggers at the end of the 10:30 bar... and yet it is triggered at the start of the bar...

How to resolve this issue

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try **alert** with [alert.freq_once_per_bar_close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_alert%7Bdot%7Dfreq_once_per_bar_close)

something like that:

```
if buySignal
    alert("Buy!", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: I need to use alertcondition.

The alert needs to trigger a webhook for buy and sell which means I need to use two alertconditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay it by one bar, you can do:

```
alertcondition(buySignal[1] and barstate.isconfirmed, title="Alert Buy", message="Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal[1] and barstate.isconfirmed, title="Alert: Sell", message="Sell!")
```

Comment: Its not so much delay it one bar, the problem is that the strategy may not even trigger because at the close of the bar the trigger conditions no longer are valid but the study has already triggered by that point